# Word choice: This phenomenon (links and is beneficial with) another phenomenon

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

The situation is:

1. The U.S. - Malaysian exchange rate is good
2. The U.S. interest rate is low.

My sentence wishes to express that the 2nd situation links to the first and both are beneficial.

"This (low interest rate) ______ with the good exchange rate"

What word should I use?

Answer (score 1):

You could try complements:

> "This low interest rate complements the U.S.-Malaysian exchange rate."

From [TFD Online](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/complement)

> **complement** *v. tr.*
>   1.
>   a. Something that completes, makes up a whole, or brings to perfection: *a sauce that is a fine complement to fish*.

Answer (score 0):

You may use 'Ascribe'.
Ascribe means credit to or attributed.
"This (low interest rate) ascribes with the good exchange rate".